# Does changing my server password require new SSH keys?

Tags: ssh

I am using a SSH key to connect to a server.  If I go onto the remote host and modify my password will this require generating new SSH keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

By logging in with a Public / Private key pair you are replacing the password normally used. This is also the reason you don't need a new key pair for ever server, just one works for them all.

Answer (score 3):

No, your keys are stored in your client machine, as long as the passphrase to decrypt them.
The password of the remote user is independent from the SSH keys.